# Prove that there exist infinite number of solutions to an integer equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that there exist infinitely many pairs  $(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, such that $(x-y)^7=x^3 y^3$

I've already got the solution in comment, but is there detailed procedure and detailed method to get that solution?

Comment: I don't think so. Wolfram gives only $2$.

Comment: Try $(x,y)=(a^3(a+1)^4, a^4(a+1)^3), \ a\in \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: @wwwrqnojcm: Yes, that looks like a solution. What is your question, then?

Comment: So, you've found infinitely many solutions, @wwwrqnojcm? Aren't you done?

Comment: But is there detailed procedure to get that solution? I mean what is the method to find that pair of (x,y)? I also posted this question on AoPS but only got an answer instead of detailed procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is what I did to get the same answer:

Define the positive integer $d=x-y$. We can rewrite the equation $(x-y)^7=x^3y^3$ as: 
$$ d^7 = (d+y)^3y^3 $$
From this we can see that $y$ must be a multiple of $d$ (since the right-hand-side must be a multiple of $d$). So we can write $y=ad$ for some positive integer $a$.  From that we get: 
$$ d^7 = (d+ad)^3a^3d^3 $$
Simplifying gives $d=a^3(1+a)^3$. So we can choose $a$ to be any positive integer we like, and then define $d=a^3(1+a)^3$.  The result is the same as your answer.  This also proves that it is the only possible answer.